# Foundation Variables and Mixins Not Working Correctly

Tags: variables, sass, zurb-foundation, mixins

I have [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/) installed with Bower, and I'm including the path in my gulp task like so:

```
.pipe(sass({
    includePaths: [
        'bower_components/foundation/scss'
    ],
    outputStyle: 'expanded'
})
```

When I `@import 'foundation';` into my stylesheet it seems to work fine. But when I start to reference its SASS variables or mixins I start getting errors like the one below:

```
Error: unbound variable $medium-up
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You need to `@import 'foundation/settings';` before `@import 'foundation';`. As far as I can see, [the main file](https://github.com/zurb/foundation/blob/080bf596b0a7d65751507650c5ec750bf71f4eb7/scss/foundation.scss) that you are importing does not include settings.

Take a look at the *app.scss* section in [this doc](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/using-sass.html).

Answer (score 0):

the trick is to import settings.SCSS file in the bottom of global.scss. Works perfect for me